# Section of direct-sum and tensor product of line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have a variety $X$ and suppose that I have three line bundles $L_1, L_2$ and $L_3$ over $X$ such that $L_1 \oplus L_2 \oplus (L_2 \otimes L_3)$ has a nonzero global section. Does it imply that we have a nonzero global section of the bundle $L_1 \oplus L_2 \oplus L_3$ ?

Comment: Yes. Take $X$ to be a smooth projective curve, then there is a nontrivial line bundle $L$ whose square is trivial. Then $L$ has no nontrivial global sections. Take $L_1=L_2=L_3=L$.

Comment: @Aphelli: you say "Yes", but probably mean "No", right?

Comment: Can we put some conditions on $L_i$ such that the answer is affirmative ?

Comment: Hi, In my opinion, the condition that $L_2$ has a nonzero global section is enough to get an affirmative answer.

Comment: You can also take any non-trivial line bundle $L$, put $L_1=L_2=L$ and $L_3=L^*$, the dual line bundle. Then $L_2\]otimes L_3=L\otimes L^*$ has a canonical nowhere vanishing section (corresponding to the identity map), but $L^*$ is non-trivial since $L$ non-trivial.

Comment: @Sasha: you’re right, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @sti9111: How do you use the nonzero global section of $L_2$ to construct a nonzero section of  $L_1 \oplus L_2 \oplus L_3$ ?

Comment: Since, $H^0(X,L_1\oplus L_2 \oplus L_3)\cong H^0(X,L_1)\oplus H^0(X,L_2)\oplus H^0(X,L_3)$, then if $H^0(X,L_2)$ is not trivial this implies that  $L_1\oplus L_2 \oplus L_3$ has a nonzero global section.

Comment: Is this question in the context of algebraic geometry? Cause this question has the algebraic-topology and differential-geometry tags and you're not specifying in the post with what kinds of bundles and what kinds of sections you're working with. In the continuous or smooth categories, the answers become very different compared to the algebro- or complex-geometric settings.

Comment: Yes, it is from algebraic geometry.

Comment: @Thorgott, I believe that the question is clear even with your suggestions, because the word Variety is in the context of algebraic geometry, and the bundles are lines bundles.

Comment: @sti9111 variety can also be used for a manifold in French. More importantly, tags should be clear and specific - if this question doesn't have a relation to algebraic topology or differential geometry, those tags shouldn't appear here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is No. It is because you can take $X$ to be an Enriques surface; for this type of surface $K_X$ is not trivial, but $H^0(X, K_X)=\{0\}$ and $K_X\otimes K_X= 2K_X\sim \mathcal{O}_X$. Then, taking $L_i=K_X$, the expression
$L_1\oplus L_2 \oplus (L_2\otimes L_3)= K_X\oplus K_X \oplus \mathcal{O}_X$, but
$L_1\oplus L_2\oplus L_3= K_X\oplus K_X \oplus K_X$.
This is basically the @Aphelli answer.

Comment: nice answer .......+1